# Dialog for security questions on login with jQuery Mobile App

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm currently looking for a better way to do this. I have to create a series of dialog popups for risk based security on this application I am working with. I have the dialogs set up with simpledialog2 BUT I know there may be a better way, maybe only one dialog with content dynamically changing out? Also with these separate dialogs I have the issue of setting the last dialog to close, it closes the next as well. If anyone has a good idea what is best in this situation, I'd greatly appreciate the help. I have spent a few days researching and find nothing on this subject. Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
$(document).delegate('#security-questions', 'click', function() {
            $('<div>').simpledialog2({
              mode: 'blank',
              headerText: 'Security Questions',
              headerClose: true,
              blankContent : 
                "<div class='question-content'><p>Please choose 5 of the following security questions and provide answers:</p><div data-role='fieldcontain'><select name='question-one-select' id='question-one-select'><option value='None'>Please choose a question:</option><option value='1'>What is your favorite pizza topping?</option><option value='2'>Who is the person you admire the most?</option><option value='3'>Who is your favorite actor, actress or celebrity?</option><option value='4'>What is your favorite television show?</option><option value='5'>What is the name of the first person you were romantically interested in?</option></select></div><div id='firstq-div' data-role='fieldcontain'><input type='text' name='question-one' id='question-one' placeholder='Answer' /></div><a href='#' id='second-question' data-role='button' data-rel='dialog'>Next</a></div>"
            });
        });

        $(document).delegate('#second-question', 'click', function() {
            $('<div>').simpledialog2({
              mode: 'blank',
              headerText: 'Question 2',
              headerClose: true,
              blankContent : 
                "<div class='question-content'><div data-role='fieldcontain'><select name='question-two-select' id='question-two-select'><option value='None'>Please choose a question:</option><option value='1'>What is your favorite pizza topping?</option><option value='2'>Who is the person you admire the most?</option><option value='3'>Who is your favorite actor, actress or celebrity?</option><option value='4'>What is your favorite television show?</option><option value='5'>What is the name of the first person you were romantically interested in?</option></select></div><div id='secondq-div' data-role='fieldcontain'><input type='text' name='question-two' id='question-two' placeholder='Answer' /></div><a href='#' id='third-question' data-role='button' data-rel='dialog'>Next</a></div>"
            });
        });

        $(document).delegate('#third-question', 'click', function() {
            $('<div>').simpledialog2({
              mode: 'blank',
              headerText: 'Question 3',
              headerClose: true,
              blankContent : 
                "<div class='question-content'><div data-role='fieldcontain'><select name='question-three-select' id='question-three-select'><option value='None'>Please choose a question:</option><option value='1'>What is your favorite pizza topping?</option><option value='2'>Who is the person you admire the most?</option><option value='3'>Who is your favorite actor, actress or celebrity?</option><option value='4'>What is your favorite television show?</option><option value='5'>What is the name of the first person you were romantically interested in?</option></select></div><div id='thirdq-div' data-role='fieldcontain'><input type='text' name='question-three' id='question-three' placeholder='Answer' /></div><a href='#' id='fourth-question' data-role='button' data-rel='dialog'>Next</a></div>"
            });
        });

        $(document).delegate('#fourth-question', 'click', function() {
            $('<div>').simpledialog2({
              mode: 'blank',
              headerText: 'Question 4',
              headerClose: true,
              blankContent : 
                "<div class='question-content'><div data-role='fieldcontain'><select name='question-four-select' id='question-four-select'><option value='None'>Please choose a question:</option><option value='1'>What is your favorite pizza topping?</option><option value='2'>Who is the person you admire the most?</option><option value='3'>Who is your favorite actor, actress or celebrity?</option><option value='4'>What is your favorite television show?</option><option value='5'>What is the name of the first person you were romantically interested in?</option></select></div><div id='fourthq-div' data-role='fieldcontain'><input type='text' name='question-four' id='question-four' placeholder='Answer' /></div><a href='#' id='fifth-question' data-role='button' data-rel='dialog'>Next</a></div>"
            });
        });

        $(document).delegate('#fifth-question', 'click', function() {
            $('<div>').simpledialog2({
              mode: 'blank',
              headerText: 'Question 5',
              headerClose: true,
              blankContent : 
                "<div class='question-content'><div data-role='fieldcontain'><select name='question-five-select' id='question-five-select'><option value='None'>Please choose a question:</option><option value='1'>What is your favorite pizza topping?</option><option value='2'>Who is the person you admire the most?</option><option value='3'>Who is your favorite actor, actress or celebrity?</option><option value='4'>What is your favorite television show?</option><option value='5'>What is the name of the first person you were romantically interested in?</option></select></div><div id='fifthq-div' data-role='fieldcontain'><input type='text' name='question-five' id='question-five' placeholder='Answer' /></div><a href='#' id='finish-question' data-role='button' data-rel='dialog'>Done</a></div>"
            });
        });
```

Comment: I've read this 3 times and it is still not clear to me what you are asking or describing.

Comment: Sorry, I have these five dialogs. Each will be a series of questions you choose for security. After you choose a question and answer it, you hit next and you choose a different question and answer that, until you have chose and answered five. Now my issue is #1. I can't get the last dialog to close when the new one opens. I have added a few different solutions to close the current dialog as the next opens, but it also closes the dialog that just opened.

Comment: I also wonder if I should/could consolidate these into one dialog that when the next button is clicked it will dynamically change to choose your next question, instead of having 5 dialogs. Hope that makes a little more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the close issue, you need to call the method to close the current dialog. The easiest way to do this is to use the global datapoint in `$.mobile`. At the start of the handler that opens a subsequent dialog, close the current before opening the next

Simplified code sample:

```
$( '#dialog2' ).click( function(){
  // close the current dialog
  $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.close();

  // open the next one
  $('<div>').simpledialog2( {...} );
});
```

To replace the current content, change your handler to just use the updateBlank() method.

```
$( '#dialog2' ).click( function(){
  // update the contents in the current blank-mode dialog
  $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.updateBlank( '<p>The next question</p>...' );
});
```

This is all clearly documented on page 3 of the docs. Go to the homepage for simpledialog2. Just click the main menu link to `Methods, Events and Data` to get here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/event.html

Comment: The second part is exactly what I was look for, I totally overlooked that in the docs. :( As for the close that I did try and wasn't working so I was lost. Thank you @Cheekysoft!